# User input to display 5 rows at a time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-input

I need to write a Python function that asks the user if they'd like to see 5 rows of the raw data, then if they say yes, display the first 5 rows and then ask if they'd like to see 5 more, and so on, until they say no. We are using Pandas dataframes. Any suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried a few different things, with while loops, .iloc, indexing, but just can't quite get there

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us what you tried and what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you may try pandas.DataFrame.head, the api address:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html